# Error when building C mex files in Matlab: permission denied

Tags: matlab, mex

I have tried to compile C code in matlab.

I tested with the simple example code in the `matlabroot/extern/examples` subfolders. I did the following:

```
mex -setup
copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','mex', 'yprime.c'), './');
mex -v -g yprime.c
```

The command line outputs the following information, which I guess should be  a path problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
**************************************************************************
 Warning: Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected. 
           Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require
           the use of -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims
           option. For more information, see:
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html
**************************************************************************

find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
cfind: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /Library/Application Support/Apple/ParentalControls/Users: Permission denied
find: /Library/PreferencePanes/TeXDistPrefPane.prefPane: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/active: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/bounce: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/corrupt: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/defer: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/deferred: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/flush: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/hold: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/incoming: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/maildrop: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/private: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/public: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/saved: Permission denied
find: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool/trace: Permission denied
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: try adding `-v` to your mex command to see some debug info: `mex -g -v prime.c` and let us see what verbose information it spits out.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the information, but it is pretty much the same as I got before.

Comment: when `mex -setup` what did you choose? what compiler are you using on what machine?

Comment: I have only 1 option when ``mex -setup``  ``1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mexopts.sh``, and I am using Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: I recently have had the similar problem. This is indeed annoying because I cannot build any mex C file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the mex file has been called before by any instance of Matlab. In this case, clear all variables at each instance using "clear all" command and try again. Also, some other process of your operating system may be locking the mex file. Try to find out who is locking that file and unlock it.